# Is the [c#3.0] tag new, and should it exist?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-creation, new-tags-page

What happened here?

[image: 1175 new c#3.0 questions]
<sub>(source: [tejp.de](http://tejp.de/files/linked/img/so-tag-csharp30.png))</sub>

Was it a retag? (I couldn't find any `[retag-request]` about this.)

If it's the result of a retag, shouldn't the tag rather be `[c#-3.0]`? This format seems to have become the canonical "language version" format (see the existing [tag synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms)).

On the other hand, the other C# version tags like `[c#2.0]`) also don't contain a hyphen.

Should the tags for special C# versions be hyphened, or not? Is `[c#x.0]` preferable, or should `[c#-x.0]` be used, which would be consistent with other languages?

Comment: Hm... there seem to be whole buckets of oddities in [tag creation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54384/new-tags-page-attributes-a-tag-to-an-edit-that-never-happened-and-to-an-author-t) these days...

Answer (score 2):

`C#3.0` should exist as a tag. There are features that are specific to C# 3.0 like LINQ and anonymous object initialization.

It should be whatever the convention for language version tags is. If it's `C#-x.0` then so be it.

Comment: I don't think this was ever in question, it was just whether or not a `-` should be part of the tag

Comment: The title of the question is 'should it exist'? Thats'w here I got that idea from.

Comment: Ah, I see. I interpreted that as "should it exist, or should it be [c#-3.0] instead", not "should it exist, or should all c# questions be under one tag"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's new. I was going to file a retag request a few days ago to go the other way (`[c#x]` to `[c#-x]`), but there are already tag synonyms to do so, they just [aren't applied retroactively](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57626/unable-to-change-certain-new-tags). I didn't exactly follow why that is, but I suspect when they finish implementing tag synonyms they're going to apply them to all the old posts in a mass retag

Comment: I don't see any such tag synonyms on http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms

Comment: I blew off the synonym it was the wrong way around

Comment: @waffles Oh good, I'm not insane