# Can't edit tags

Tags: support, tags, edits, tag-synonyms

I have a problem with editing a tag on SO. Here is the question I try to edit:
[Bitfield enum extension method to return dictionary of included values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195679/bitfield-enum-extension-method-to-return-dictionary-of-included-values)

I'd like to replace the *bit-fields* tag by *bitfields*, but it just doesn't work (neither in the moderators quick edit, nor in the normal question-edit).

I tried to edit with Opera, Chrome and IE. Nothing works. Strangly, I can edit tags of other questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a [tag synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) that maps bitfields to bit-fields (the [info page for [bit-fields]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=bit-fields&sort=info&pagesize=15) also shows them). I had a [similar problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57626/unable-to-change-certain-new-tags) last week with [c#-3.0] and [java-fx]

Comment: OK, that answered all my questions ^^ Well ... beside ... why is there no notice on the GUI?

Comment: @tanascius There was a [discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56685/tag-synonyms-the-user-experience) of what to show the user when a tag is remapped; the common use case is going to be users using the wrong tag, and it should just be silently fixed. It is rather confusing for retaggers though, so it might change

Comment: @tanascius: I [tried to warn them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56685/tag-synonyms-the-user-experience/56690#56690)...

Comment: @Jon Maybe it could just show a warning if you do a retagging edit, but not on the original post of a question?

Comment: @Michael: Suggest that and I'll upvote it.

Comment: @Michael: To me at least, it makes more sense if the system notifies the user *every time* there is invalid input.

Comment: @Jon if we implemented everything from day one, you would still have to wait 6-8 weeks for tag synonyms to show up on the site :) we are only getting a tiny amount of issues on meta considering there are a few hundred synonyms in play now.